# Prototype.js conflicting with jquery.js : How to solve this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototypejs, conflict

I have `parent.jsp`, which contains `prototype.js`. The `parent.jsp` contains a link , which loads contents from `child.jsp`, but the `child.jsp` contains `jquery.js`. Now prototype is conflicting with jquery and i get a whole lot of errors in  internet explorer and one error in mozilla firefox.

Most of internet explorer problems are referring to `$` symbol and `document.body.appendChild()`.

The mozilla firefox is giving this error:

`typeerror value does not implement interface node` in this line of prototype :

`var query= document.evaluate(expression, $(parentElement) || document, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null);`

Can any one suggest how to solve this problem ? I have googled a lot, given `noConflict` for jquery, still nothing is working .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay so , i found out the problem, it seems all this problem was because of jquery.js getting loaded twice, once from child.jsp and again from another page. Hut!!!.

That was horrible, took me forever to find that out.

Answer (score 1):

Refer to jQuery noConflict docs: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/#example-1

Use this example in you child page:

```
jQuery.noConflict();
(function($) {
  $(function() {
   // put your jquery code in here
  });
})(jQuery);
// other code using $ as an alias to the other library
```

Comment: Look at my question, i have used `noConflict`, wasn't of much help .

Comment: I think if you use a self executing function you don't need the `noConflict()` call.

Answer (score 0):

If your conflicting issue not resolving even after putting `noConflict` script, replace all '$' symbol with 'jQuery' throughout your jquery code.